# Confusing definition of multidimensional arrays in C++ Primer

Tags: c++, arrays

The book provides the following example:

```c++
int arr[10][20][30] = {0}; // initialize all elements to 0
```

My current understanding: It's one array of size 10, containing 10 elements, all of which are arrays themselves, of size 20, containing 20 elements, all of which are arrays themselves, of size 30, containing 30 elements, all of which are `int`.

The way the book puts it:

> First we see that `arr` is an array of
> size 10. The elements of that array are themselves arrays of size 20. **Each of those
> arrays has 30 elements that are of type `int`**.

No: each of those 20 elements are arrays of size 30, composed by 30 elements of type `int`.

Do I have terrible reading comprehension or is the book wrong?

Comment: Your understanding and the way the book puts it both say the same thing to me.

Comment: I'm obviously overthinking this, but I need to be somewhat critical to understand this by myself, and arrays of size 20 can't fit 30 elements, can they?

Comment: @sanzio the arrays of size 20 aren't fitting 30 elements. Each element in the array of size 20 is itself an array of size 30.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I have terrible reading comprehension or is the book wrong?

[The book seems to say what's in your quote.](https://books.google.com/books?id=J1HMLyxqJfgC&pg=PT264&lpg=PT264&dq=%22First%20we%20see%20that%20arr%20is%20an%20array%20of%20size%2010.%22&source=bl&ots=FKPG0i3icr&sig=ACfU3U041CVxmkXBXQsbTSuYumtsmTQRbA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_r_WV2NbxAhWQbs0KHSoaDOMQ6AEwAHoECAQQAw#v=onepage&q=%22First%20we%20see%20that%20arr%20is%20an%20array%20of%20size%2010.%22&f=false)

It's worded *poorly*, in my opinion.

Without speculating on the authors' intent, it could perhaps be more clearly written as:

> First we see that `arr` is an array of size 10. The elements of that array are themselves arrays of size 20. Each **element of that array is an array of** 30 elements that are of type `int`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to better understand what is actually going on a visualization may be helpful. I'm going to use a much smaller example so it's easier to visualize, but the concept is the same.

Consider the following:

`int arr[2][3][4] = {0}; // initialize all elements to 0`

Here we start with an array of size 2. Each of these two elements is an array of size 3. Each of these three elements is an array of size 4. Each of those 4 elements are ints.

```
arr -> [0] -> [0] -> [0] int
    |      |      -> [1] int
    |      |      -> [2] int
    |      |      -> [3] int
    |      -> [1] -> [0] int
    |      |      -> [1] int
    |      |      -> [2] int
    |      |      -> [3] int
    |      -> [2] -> [0] int
    |             -> [1] int
    |             -> [2] int
    |             -> [3] int
    -> [1] -> [0] -> [0] int
           |      -> [1] int
           |      -> [2] int
           |      -> [3] int
           -> [1] -> [0] int
           |      -> [1] int
           |      -> [2] int
           |      -> [3] int
           -> [2] -> [0] int
                  -> [1] int
                  -> [2] int
                  -> [3] int
```

This is a much smaller array of arrays of arrays than in your example, but as you can see it is still quite a large amount of elements altogether.

You still must index into each array until you get to the third level. So the minimum element would be `arr[0][0][0]` and assignments such as  `arr[0][0][0] = 5` are valid. Consequentially, the maximum element would be `arr[1][2][3]` in my example. Follow the tree I drew above to see how you would go about accessing each element.

Answer (score 2):

to make is comprehensible understand by these schema

> an `2d` array is collection of `1d`array &`3d` array as a collection of `2d array`

like as your example above you understand that if a array of size n
in created as `int array[n]` the array should contained n elements in row
just like this if a 2d array exist as `int array[n][m]` that means in 2d array setup you got n elements in m rows

in 1 d array we got n element for only one row/vector
whereas in 2 d array these row is < 1 means you got your n elements in array but for m times
in terminology this setup is known as matrix (mathematically) you will be already familiar with this and m,n are known to be rows and column

when you understand above stuff it will be more easier to understand `3d array` like i said understand `3d array` as a collection of `2d array`
for example most common visualization be cube

in a cube we got stack of 2d array that joined together to make it 3 dimensional
like in rgb digital image for all separate 3 channels of green,red,blue we got respective intensity values at x,y plane or (m,n) matrix position

in c++/c native programming
`int array[a][b][c]` or `int ***array` both creates 3d array
for simplicity consider 1st one
and consider as
c no of elements situated on a*b plane or (a,b) matrix c times
i doesn't know it become more comprehensible and understandable to you or it become complex

just in case you don't understand compare this in real life scenario
consider 2d array as:
list of seats in stadium/classroom
there are n seats which repeat for m times or rows
consider 3d array as:
all the seats in a  school building/ (low styles seats+balcony seats) AS All 2d array seats are now considering in one list/one entity i.e. 3d array

Comment: Each individual array address at `int array[a][b][c]` is an `int ***` but `int array[a][b][c]` != `int ***`.

Comment: `int ***array` is not also a way of creating a 3D array. It's strictly a triple pointer without any additional context. In fact, on it's own you would need multiple levels of `malloc`'s to make it behave like an array.